# Azure - create dashboard for past 90 days activity logs

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-log-analytics

I want to create dashboard for past 90 days activity logs via log analytic workspace where I have created log analytic workspace one day ago.
so can we get logs in log analytic workspace ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can configure your application Insights Resources to send events to Log Analytics, other services like AFD and WAF etc can send metrics directly to log analytics.

The App Insights configuration option can be found under the Configure -> Properties section in the portal

Once you have configured the logs and metrics to be sent to your workspace you just need have to write the queries and then PIN them to an Azure Dashboard